# Read column from Sql and populate to listbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I'm having problem with my sql query.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" + "Trusted_Connection=True;" + "User Instance=True;" + "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\fbi.mdf;";
        string sqlQuery4 = "SELECT Car FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.userID = tbl2.userID) WHERE tbl2.username='Bob'";
        SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery4, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
        rd.Read();
        ddl1.Items.Add(rd.GetValue(0).ToString());
        conn.Close();
```

So it should return all cars from tbl1 that belongs to Bob. Query only return one string and put it into Listbox "ddl1" while it should return at least 3 of them.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the reader:

```
while (rd.Read()){
   ddl1.Items.Add(rd.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
```

Comment: It's getting closer but it is not perfect yet. First It was returning first(1 out of 3) car. Now it only return third (3 out of 3) car. So it's sending only one string. I think i might need to use array or data table here?

Answer (score 0):

Novak, not sure what your issue was with Curt's solution, as it is correct. Your complete statement should look like:

```
string connectionString= "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=True;User Instance=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\fbi.mdf;";
string query = "SELECT Car FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.userID = tbl2.userID) WHERE tbl2.username='Bob'";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ddl1.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad guys .You both are right. It was my error.
I was calling reader twice in my code:

    rd.Read();
           while (rd.Read())
           {
               string car = rd.GetString(0);
                    ddl1.Items.Add(car);
                
           }

I deleted line:

    rd.Read();

and it's all working fine.
Thanks to both of You.

Comment: NP... thought there might've just been extra code in your initial attempt. Ensure you use the *using* statements, and if you start to use user input as the *username* value, use parameters.

Comment: yep, the magic is starting here : I want to take input from:   "asp:LoginView" so depending on who is currently logged in, different cars will be displayed. But that is another story :)

Comment: Yeah if you have problems with authentication, start another question. But I can tell you, LoginView is not the way to get the logged in users name.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" + "Trusted_Connection=True;" + "User Instance=True;" + "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\fbi.mdf;";
        string sqlQuery4 = "SELECT Car FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.userID = tbl2.userID) WHERE tbl2.username='Bob'";
        SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery4, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd4.ExecuteReader();


                ddl1.DataSource = rd;
                ddl1..DataTextField = "columnname"; //your column name
                ddl1.DataValueField = "columnname";
                ddl1.DataBind();

                rd.Close();
                conn.Close();
```